# My phone transformed into my dad's phone HELP!

Tags: iphone

My phone was charging on our family laptop and my phone said "Restoring in process" I didn't press anything but I also didn't think anything of it. Well when it was done restoring everything changed and then I realized it was my dad's phone due to the contacts and pictures. Although, my phone still has my number connected to it instead of my dad's.  How do I transform it back into my phone without losing contacts on both phones?

Answer (score 1):

(connect to wifi)go to icloud in settings if you see yor dad's, need to long out with his icloud password  (do not delete account might delete his backup). Disable find my iphone. Then simply log your apple ID and restore your iPhone from backup, iTunes should have created one before it restored his. Turn find my iPhone back on for security.